# What is the iml file used for when using Android Studio?

Tags: android

What is the iml file used for when using Android Studio? Why is it generated? 
I have found it in each module. The android official document says nothing about it.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio is based on IntelliJ IDEA. The `iml` file is the config file for project or module.